# next-auth [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement Google OAuth using next-auth. My problem is when I try logging in using Google as the provider, right as I click the button it redirects me to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error: PICTURE [error path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUtpy.png) . What I'm trying to accomplish is when you click the "Sign in with Google" button, it redirects you to Google's OAuth page.

**Console error:**

> [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
> Object { error: {…}, url: "/api/auth/providers", message: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." }

**What I've tried:**

- Resetting my GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, and NEXTAUTH_SECRET
- Adding "secret: NEXTAUTH_SECRET" as an option above providers to my [...nextauth].ts file, even though according to the docs it is not needed
- Inputting localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google directly into the URL, which worked and I was able to access my session object in my homepage. It sent me here [OAuth Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDJuk.png)
- Updated next-auth from 4.14.0 to 4.15.0
- Cleared cookies and sessions from http://localhost:3000
- Deployed on Vercel with proper environment variables and added the domain to Google credentials, then tried to login from my phone with and without wifi and from my PC.
- Tried logging in using FireFox, FireFox incognito mode, Google Chrome, Google Chrome incognito mode
- Tried using signIn() without any arguments
- Spent hours trying many possible solutions given in StackOverflow and Nextjs's official github issues section

**/client/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts:**

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

**/client/pages/login.tsx OAuth component with props passed to a button:**

```
  <OAuth
    company={"Google"}
    handleLogin={() =>
      signIn("google", { callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/" })
    }
  />
```

**/client/.env file:**

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=***********
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=***********

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=122a918b879a0d7e331c0795f435d084
```

Inside my Google Developers Credentials, I have

- http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google inside the Authorized redirect URIs section
- http://localhost:3000 inside the Authorized JavaScript origins section

**--EDIT: Found a fix.--**

**Solution:**

```
  <OAuth
    company={"Google"}
    handleLogin={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      signIn("google", { callbackUrl: REDIRECT_URL_AFTER_SIGN_IN });
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a fix and added it to the bottom of the post. The only change I made was adding e.preventDefault() before invoking signIn(). If anyone could explain why this works that would be great!

Comment: This worked for me too. Did you ever figure out why?

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me as well

Comment: I can't say for sure, but usually `e.preventDefault()` fixes things by preventing the default form submission action.  If you don't have an `onSubmit` with an `e.preventDefault()`, the browser automatically does the "default" action of redirecting you to the URL in the `<form>` tag's `action` attribute ... or, if you haven't specified one, the browser simply reloads the page.  Presumably next-auth is using a form without this protection.

Comment: This is not working for me, any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nextjs 14 and app directory and nothing above is working, try making a pages directory and moving the auth folder there.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No Idea really as to why this works, but It worked for me as well.

I had a custom button component that would do the same thing, it always took 2 clicks to of sighn in to actually get the google sign in page to show up. After adding e.preventDefault(), that problem went away.

For reference I am using Next.js v13, NextAuth and Google as the Auth Provider.

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import { Button } from './Button'

export default function LoginButton() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          variant="solid"
          color="blue"
          className="my-10 w-full"
          onClick={() => signOut('google', { callbackUrl: '/' })}
        >
          Sign out
        </Button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        type="submit"
        variant="solid"
        color="blue"
        className="my-10px w-full"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          signIn('google', {
            callbackUrl: '/Dashboard/DefaultDash',
          })
        }}
      >
        Sign in with google
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

EDIT: After digging a litte deeper, I think its because by default google is expecting a call/argument looking for a CRSF token, or Cross-Site Request Forgery token. By using preventDefault() it bypasses that requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar error:

> [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I solve it by deleting another api folder that was located at the same directory level as the pages directory, I was able to fix the issue. Hope that was helpful.